# contain text in collection - Magento2

Tags: magento2, collection, magento-2.0, filter

I am trying to **filter the collection based on contain string**

It is working

```
$collection = $this->_chennaidbFactory->create()->getCollection()
            ->addFilter('event_date',['like'=>'2016-05-21 16:00:00'])
            ->setOrder('event_date', 'DESC');
```

It is not working, ($datepicker carry yyyy-mm-dd)

```
$collection = $this->_chennaidbFactory->create()->getCollection()
            ->addFilter('event_date',['like'=>'%'.$datepicker.'%'])
            ->setOrder('event_date', 'DESC');
```

also tried like many way

```
addFilter('event_date',['like'=>'%2016-05-21%'])
addFilter('event_date',['like'=>'2016-05-21%'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Magento 2 uses a method to generate that like condition.

First you need to inject `\Magento\Framework\DB\Helper` in your constructor:

```
protected $_resourceHelper;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Helper $resourceHelper
) {
    $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
    ...
}
```

Then to generate the like part of your filter you can do:

```
$escapedDatePart = $this->_resourceHelper->addLikeEscape(
        $datepicker,
        ['position' => 'any']
    );
```

Please note that the `position` can be one of the following value:

- `any` for `%value%`
- `start` for `value%`
- `end` for `%value`

Then to filter your collection you can call:

```
->addFieldToFilter('event_date',['like'=>$escapedDatePart]);
```